# How to remove excess whitespace in matplotlib legend for PGF plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, latex, pgf

I'm creating a fairly small plot with matplotlib which needs to include a certain legend. However, while space is tight, for some reason matplotlib makes the legend excessively wide, adding a lot of whitespace to the right part of the legend:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Although I can't give all the code to reproduce this figure, here are some parts that might be relevant:

```
text_width_in_inches = 5.95114 # Used to scale PGF plots
very_small_font_size = 5
small_font_size = 7
medium_font_size = 9
thin_line_width = 0.75
small_marker_size = 3.75
...
def set_plot_width(fig, text_width_ratio):
    old_width, old_height = fig.get_size_inches()
    new_width = text_width_ratio*text_width_in_inches
    new_height = (new_width/old_width)*old_height
    fig.set_size_inches(new_width, new_height)
...
matplotlib.use("pgf")
matplotlib.rcParams.update({
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
    'font.family': 'serif',
    'text.usetex': True,
    'pgf.rcfonts': False,
    'axes.labelsize': small_font_size,
    'axes.titlesize': medium_font_size,
    'xtick.labelsize': small_font_size,
    'ytick.labelsize': small_font_size,
    'legend.fontsize': small_font_size,
    'lines.linewidth': thin_line_width,
    'lines.markersize': small_marker_size,
})
...
plt.legend(fontsize=very_small_font_size)
plt.xlabel("Mode storage order")
plt.ylabel("Normalized compression factor")
plt.ylim(miny, maxy)
set_plot_width(plt.gcf(), 0.4 if len(mode_storage_orders) <= 10 else 0.6)
plt.savefig(figure_path + dataset_name.replace(" ", "-") + "-core-flattenings.pgf", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.close()
```

As you can see, I'm rendering the plot to a PGF file so that it can be included directly in my Latex document with matching fonts etc. However, this might be part of the problem: when I switch back to my default "TkAgg" back-end, remove a few Latex/PGF-related rcParams settings and save the plot to a PNG file, I get the following result:

[image]

which fixes the legend problem, but is not what I want of course.

Finally, I also tried messing a bit with certain legend kwargs, such as `borderpad` and `columnspacing`, but this didn't help.

Comment: `plt.legend(prop={'size':50})` works for you? (you need to adjust the 50)

Comment: This indeed massively enlarges the font size, leading to legends that cover the whole page. However, I did observe that the whitespace seems to go away as I increase the font size (to 10 for example), indicating that, perhaps, matplotlib has some default minimal legend width. My next bet now would be to set the position, width and height of the legend explicitly using `bbox_to_anchor`, however that would require a lot of hardcoding.